# Netflix tearing in Chrome 14.04 with AMD graphics card

Tags: 14.04, ati

I'm experiencing heavy tearing while watching Netflix through Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Here are my system specs:

- 3.6 GB RAM
- AMD Athlon II X2 250 Processors (x2)
- Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880

I've tried forcing hardware acceleration through Chrome, and tried increasing the Chrome's process priority. I've seen fixes for old version of Ubuntu and NVIDIA cards, but nothing for AMD or watching Netflix through Chrome.

It's work noting I don't have any tearing when watching videos on VLC.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Should I give up on Chrome and try Kodi or something else?